# Memory Profiler

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, profiling, profiler

Need to create our own Java profiler. The CPU profiling part was done with the help of Build your own profiler article from IBM. Now checking for similar kind for memory profiling also. On search found Hprof, but it was not useful to me. What i want is get the memory consumed in bytes by each method in a class

For eg:

consider a class `test1` , class `test2` etc are there in java file

`method1()` is present in test1

`method2()` is present in test2

many variables will be declared inside each methods
So what i want is like

test1/method1 =   12 bytes (if possible display trace i.e how it came like this much number of char + number of integers etc)

test2/method2 = 18bytes

Please help

Comment: Are you talking purely about local variables? Or about objects created in those methods?

Comment: You cannot do this without interrogating the JVM itself.  Any particular reason you cannot use jvisualvm in the JDK or the Attach API?

Comment: `Need to create our own Java profiler` Can you clarify why you feel you need to do this? This is non-trivial and is provided by commercial profilers already.

Comment: local variables as well as objects

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in how much memory a given method takes *on the stack* then there are [two attributes in the class files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546) that give information on this:

`max_locals` tells you how much space is reserved for local variables (in 32bit increments, i.e. multiply it by 4 to get the bytes).

`max_stack` tells you the largest the operand stack can grow to during execution of this method.

Adding those two will give you a *rough estimate* about how much the stack will grow if you invoke this method. There will be an additional (probably constant) overhead in addition to these values, but those should be the major variable factors.

You could use a Byte Code Manipulation Library such as [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/bcel/) to read the .class files and extract those attributes.